# if statement not evaluating but console log shows it should

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to write a function to get the length of a string without using the .length property nor any loops or built in methods. I am using recursion, however, the stopping statement is not evaluating and causing a stack overflow. I tried console logging `string[i]` and sure enough, once the length is reached, it console logs "undefined" but the if statement still won't evaluate.

```js
const getLength = (string, i = 0) => {
    if (string[i] === 'undefined') return 0;
    return 1 + getLength(string, i+1);
}

console.log(getLength("what is going on??")); //18
```

Comment: It should not, imagine what would happen, if a single character would be equal to a word of nine characters. `undefined` is a real value in JS, remove the quoting around it.

Comment: Why not simply `console.log("what is going on??".length)`?

Comment: or `if(!string)...` or `return string ? string.length : 0;`

Comment: `undefined === 'undefined'` is `false`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the point is to build a function that gets the length, rather than getting the length of some string. I'm practicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the if-state should be `string[i] === undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Your test for undefined is not working

You can test for falsy or more detailed

Here is just a falsy one, it will fail on falsy values like 0

```js
const getLength = (string, i = 0) => string[i] ?  1 + getLength(string, i+1) : 0;
console.log(getLength("what is going on??")); //18
```